# Visual Studio solution copying files on build and I can't find where this happens

Tags: visual-studio

I took over an application from a coworker that was let go and I can't figure out where this file copy process happens. When I build the solution there's an error when it tries to copy files from the solution to a network drive. I searched the code for the file copy commands and didn't find anything and there's nothing in the build events.

Where else should I look for this file copy?

Answer (score 0):

The file copy was in the build events in a second project I didn't think to check.